# Start API Network timeout

Tags: json-rpc, 0x

I am trying to start local 0x-api(https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api).
I first tried starting the api setting Infura Rpc Url in `.env` . Everything worked great. 
But I want to use my Local Ethereum node with Geth instead of Infura. So I run Geth with `--http.port 3334` because port `8545` is already in use by one of the docker images (as I understand) after `sudo docker-compose up`. 
[image]

After running Geth I can execute requests.[image]

I changed my `ETHEREUM_RPC_URL` in `.env` to **http://127.0.0.1:3334**.
After that I do `yarn`, `yarn build`, `sudo docker-compose up`, `yarn db:migrate` and then start API with `yarn start:service:swap_http`.
[image]

But after some seconds I got an error:
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make your Geth node accessible to the docker containers. From the perspective of the docker container, the geth node isn't running on 127.0.0.1. It may be accessible on your local network IP.

Comment: How can I make my Geth node accessible to the docker container? I run Geth with exact command `geth --syncmode "light" --http --http.port 3334 --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.corsdomain '*'`. Then I set ETHEREUM_RPC_URL in `.env` to `http://<my IPv4>:3334`, start swap service and get the error `"Error","msg":"network timeout at: http://<my IPv4>:3334/"`. What am I doing wrong? How to do it safely, for personal use only? I don't understand how net connections work in this situation.